# Почему нажатие на tab считается как ввод данных?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я делают тест, где проверяется соответствует ли введенное слово правильному ответу указанному в data-answer="". Все работает, но заметил, что если я перехожу с помощью кнопки TAB по полям ввода, то мой скрипт засчитывает это как не правильный ответ. Хотя данные ведь еще не начинают вводится.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.questions').find('input').keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '') === $(this).data('answer').toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')) {
      $(this).addClass('good');
      $(this).removeClass('error');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('good');
      $(this).addClass('error');
    }

    var goodAnswers = $('.good').length;
    var badAnswers = $('.error').length;

    var allInputs = $('input').length;

    jQuery('.message').html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Правильных ответов: '+ goodAnswers + ', ошибок: '+ badAnswers +' из '+ allInputs+'</div>');
  });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="message"></div>


<ol class="questions">
<li>Hva <input type="text" name="answer[1]" value="" data-answer="heter" /> du?</li>
<li><input type="text" name="answer[2]" value="" data-answer="Bor"/> du i Litauen?</li>
<li>Kommer <input type="text" name="answer[3]" value="" data-answer="du"/>på jobb i dag?</li>
<li>Hun <input type="text" name="answer[4]" value="" data-answer="heter"/>Siri.</li>
<li><input type="text" name="answer[5]" value="" data-answer="han"/>heter Tomas.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Вы будете удивлены,но у вас считает неправильный ответ даже если вы нажмёте любую другую кнопку. Потому что у вас событие keyup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видел ответ выше, но если тебе нужен именно `keyup` (у всех свои хотелки), то отлови `event` на нажатие кнопки `tab` пропускай свой код обработки

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.questions').find('input').keyup(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == '9') {
       return true; 
       // тут уже как хочется можешь обработать
    }
   
    if (this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '') === $(this).data('answer').toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')) {
      $(this).addClass('good');
      $(this).removeClass('error');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('good');
      $(this).addClass('error');
    }

    var goodAnswers = $('.good').length;
    var badAnswers = $('.error').length;

    var allInputs = $('input').length;

    jQuery('.message').html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Правильных ответов: '+ goodAnswers + ', ошибок: '+ badAnswers +' из '+ allInputs+'</div>');
  });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="message"></div>


<ol class="questions">
<li>Hva <input type="text" name="answer[1]" value="" data-answer="heter" /> du?</li>
<li><input type="text" name="answer[2]" value="" data-answer="Bor"/> du i Litauen?</li>
<li>Kommer <input type="text" name="answer[3]" value="" data-answer="du"/>på jobb i dag?</li>
<li>Hun <input type="text" name="answer[4]" value="" data-answer="heter"/>Siri.</li>
<li><input type="text" name="answer[5]" value="" data-answer="han"/>heter Tomas.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Спасибо, использую ваш вариант, нужен был именно keyup что бы человек сразу понял что ввел слово правильно. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка из за того что ты вызываешь `event` `keyup` а когда фокус пропадает из поля то оно срабатывает. а надо событием `change`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="message"></div>


<ol class="questions">
<li>Hva <input type="text" name="answer[1]" value="" data-answer="heter" /> du?</li>
<li><input type="text" name="answer[2]" value="" data-answer="Bor"/> du i Litauen?</li>
<li>Kommer <input type="text" name="answer[3]" value="" data-answer="du"/>på jobb i dag?</li>
<li>Hun <input type="text" name="answer[4]" value="" data-answer="heter"/>Siri.</li>
<li><input type="text" name="answer[5]" value="" data-answer="han"/>heter Tomas.</li>
</ol>

<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.questions').find('input').on('change',function() {
      if (this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '') === $(this).data('answer').toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')) {
        $(this).addClass('good');
        $(this).removeClass('error');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('good');
        $(this).addClass('error');
      }

      var goodAnswers = $('.good').length;
      var badAnswers = $('.error').length;

      var allInputs = $('input').length;

      jQuery('.message').html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Правильных ответов: '+ goodAnswers + ', ошибок: '+ badAnswers +' из '+ allInputs+'</div>');
    });
  
  });
    
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, но нужен был именно keyup что бы человек сразу понял что ввел слово правильно. С change получалось, что ему нужно перейти в другое поле что бы выяснилось правильно ли он ввел предыдущее.